# HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found - backend .net core, frontend react hosted on azure app service

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

I got this error when accessing react frontend. the app is hosted on the azure app service. so anyone knows how to fix this? is it need to be done in react side?

Comment: Are you able to access the application in Local ?

Comment: Pls show the error pic for us.